# Where is the config folder for JetBrains IDE?

Tags: windows-7-x64, phpstorm-2017.1

I am trying to add a custom color theme to my phpstorm and everything I read says you need to add a `colors` folder inside of the `config` folder, and then copy the xml or icls file in there, but I can't find the `config` folder.

> C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2017.1.3

I am in the right directory but there is no folder called `config` and I'm not sure what to do. Could it be in some different place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

you should find your config files under

```
c:\Users\yourname\.PhpStorm2016.1\config
```

Comment: Yes, thanks so much! Came across this page before but must have misread the directory. I thought that was the one I was looking at. Thanks again for the help.